# How to obtain Skyrim DLCs on the PS3?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have Skyrim for PS3 but not the Legendary Edition. Is it possible to download the extra content such as Hearthfire? When I go to Downloads on the main screen it doesn't give me the option for any DLC.

Comment: Have you tried the PSN store?

Comment: @kotekzot: downloadable = download-able = you're able to download :P

Answer (score -1):

You have to go to the PSN store and buy it to see it on the main screen